# Infragistics, export to excel extend named table in template

Tags: excel, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I have created an excel template where I'm trying to export a XamDataGrid to. The template contains a couple of named tables, when exporting to these tables one would expect the tables to automatically expand. However, this doesn't happen.

I tried to clear the table and create a new table with the same name, but this brakes the pivot tables using the named tables. Does anybody know, if it is possible to export to an excel template with named tables and still keep the link between the tables and pivot tables ?

**UPDATE**

It seems that infragistics doesn´t support this.